# how to select all entries that contain sub string from given array?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a table of listings for a web site. Each listing has an inherited_tags column which is a comma separated list. I want to select every listing that has a sub string in its inherited_tags column that is in an array that i give it.

So is there a way to check if any strings in an array are sub strings of a field?

Is this possible?

Is there a better way to filter listings based on tags?

Thank you.

Edit : 
i cant provide any code because i dont have any code because i dont know how to do this. Il try and explain again

i have a table of listings that have an inherited_tags field which is a string. The field contains listing tags separated by commas stored as a string.

i would like to filter this table using an array of tags.

[Table Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idLno.png)

would it be possible to use an SQL query to filter the listings depending on weather the inherited_tags string contains any items from a given array as sub strings?

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this using a MySQL query, something like the below should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE inherited_tags LIKE "%,example_tag_1,%" OR inherited_tags like "%,example_tag_2,%";
```

(This checks if example_tag_1 or example_tag_2 is in the array.)

Comment: Is this the only solution? is there no way to use an array to store the list of tags to search for? eg ['example_tag_1','example_tag_2']

Comment: What type is inherited_tags?

Comment: inherited_tags is a String

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to glean exactly what you're looking for without seeing any code but if I'm interpreting things correctly, I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
let arr = [{inhereted_tags: 'foo, bar'}, {inhereted_tags: 'foobar, baz'}, {inhereted_tags: 'baz'}];

let newArr = arr.filter(item => {
    return item.inhereted_tags.indexOf('foo') !== -1;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4h9Lv5sy/)

Comment: that works but it only allows filtering using one tag at a time. Also im trying to implement this as an SQL querry. is this possible?